# MySQL inner join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I've tried various solutions around here but I think I am missing something or that my DB structure is complete wrong. I've got the following 3 tables

```
Info (id, title, msg, status)
Countries (id, country)
Connect (infoid, countryid, status)
```

Countries table got the name of the country and a unique id per country.
Connect table is being used to connect the infoid and countryid together with a status and the info table is holding the rest of the information.

I am giving a country, for example UK, and I am trying to get the country id from the Countries table (`countries.country = UK`), then get all the available results where `connect.countryid = countries.id` and `connect.status = 1` from connect table, and finally show the title and msg from the Info table where `info.id = connect.infoid` and `info.status = 1`.

Does this make sense or is my DB structure completely wrong? And can someone please help me with the statement to achieve the above result?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: There is a question in the last sentence plus I am lost while trying to write the statement..

Comment: Your DB structure seems fine.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. You have to make an attempt, then we'll explain what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You just need to write a simple `INNER JOIN` of each table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, it is better to change the table name from Countries to Country. Or, you could use Infos and Connects to keep consistence.

You asked about your DB structure design. Firstly we need to know, what is the relationship between Countries and Info? One to one? One to many? Many to one? I guess it is many to many. It means one country might have multiple infos and one info can be shared by multiple countries.

If so, your design is OK and the code you need is shown below:

```
SELECT
    Countries.country,
    Info.title,
    Info.msg
FROM Countries
INNER JOIN Connect ON Countries.id = Connect.countryid
INNER JOIN Info ON Connect.infoid = Info.id
WHERE
    Countries.country = UK
AND Connect.status = 1
AND Info.status = 1;
```

Moreover, I still have two advices.

Firstly, do not use the column name status because it is the [Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL 5.7 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html].

Secondly, If you want to still display the country without any info, you should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Comment: Firstly I had a country row in info table but because I needed to add more countries on some entries I created that extra country table. So I've got multiple countries connected to a single info entry and multiple countries connected to multiple infos. Does this make any sense? :/

Comment: While you may disagree with the OPs naming policy, surely it their prerogative to adopt a policy of their choice.

Comment: @J.Sm Do you mean "Firstly I had a country COLUMN in info table"?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes it is their choice. However, if they asked about the good practice, I think consistence and good naming policy is improtant.

Comment: @J.Sm I have updated my answer and hope it is helpful.

Comment: @TomWang Yes I meant Column -.-". I didn't know that about the status name, I'll keep an eye for that! One last question, what do you mean if I want to display the country without any info? The only thing I want displayed are from the info table. Thank you!

Comment: @J.Sm For example, you have two country entries: UK and US. UK has 2 Info entries, info1 and info2, and US has nothing. If you use INNER JOIN, you will have two result rows, (UK, info1) and (UK, info2). If you use LEFT JOIN, you will have one more result row, (US, NULL). Sometimes people are interested in the thrid row. Moreover, regarding the column status, simply add a prefix will be helpful. Such as info_status and connect_status.

Comment: @J.Sm H J, if you are happy of the answer, could you kindly select it as the answer? Thank you.